# Custom chart suggestions

Tags: javascript, css, charts, flot

I've always use flot.js for common charting requirements, but I'd like to explore new ways to visualize data that might be beyond this charting library.  I'd appreciate any advice or recommendations as to how others might programmatically render the custom display chart below.  Maybe CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you probably weren't looking for an answer spelling out how to implement this in flot, but it was a fun exercise.

Getting creative with hiding and stacking bars with the [stack plugin](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/source/jquery.flot.stack.js) allows you to represent your bounds. For each set of bounds, you'll need to create a hidden bar with your lower bound value and then create a visible bar with your upper bound value (and stack the two). Specifying which bars should stack on each other is easy by setting the `stack` option to the same key.

Once the bars are setup, the next step is to set the options of the chart. A [grid marking](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) handles displaying the current value. Hiding [both axes](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) effectively hides the grid.

The rest comes down to creating methods to append `div` elements to placeholder to show the bar values, labels, and marking value.

This is a basic implementation of your example image that really focuses on the flot component of the chart. With a bit more time, the extra appended `div` elements could be styled in such a way to more closely match your example.

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gc1h3t7e/) contains the code below for easier review.

```js
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    data: [ [0, 21.51] ],
    lines: { show: false },
    bars: { show: false },
    stack: 0,
    label: 'Hidden'
  },{
    data: [ [1, 32.50] ],
    lines: { show: false },
    bars: { show: false },
    stack: 1,
    label: 'Hidden'
  },{
    data: [ [2, 47.14] ],
    lines: { show: false },
    bars: { show: false },
    stack: 2,
    label: 'Hidden'
  },{
    data: [ [0, 37.77] ],
    stack: 0,
    label: 'Last Year'
  },{
    data: [ [1, 24.65] ],
    stack: 1,
    label: 'Last Month'
  }, {
    data: [ [2, 7.67] ],
    stack: 2,
    label: 'Last Week'
  }];

  var options = {
    series: {
      bars: { show: true },
      points: { show: false }
    },
    xaxis: { show: false },
    yaxis: { show: false },    
    grid: { 
      show: true,
      borderWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: null,
      markings: [{ 
        xaxis: { from: 0, to: 3 },
        yaxis: { from: 48.01, to: 48.01 },
        color: "#000000"
      }]
    },
    legend: { show: false }
  };

  var plot = $.plot($('#graph'), data, options);
  var plotData = plot.getData();
  var markings = plot.getOptions().grid.markings;
  
  displayBarValues(plotData);
  displayBarLabels(plotData);
  displayMarkingValues(markings);
  
  // display values next to bars  
  function displayBarValues(plotData) {
    $.each(plotData, function(i, data) {
      var stackedValue = data.data[0][1];
     
      if (data.bars.show) {
        stackedValue = findStackedValue(plotData, data.stack);
      }
    
     var offset = plot.pointOffset({x: data.data[0][0], y: stackedValue});
    
      $('<div class="data-point-value">-- $' + stackedValue + '</div>').css( {
        left: offset.left + 30,
        top: offset.top - 8,
      }).appendTo(plot.getPlaceholder());
    });
  }

  function findStackedValue(dataSeries, stackNumber) {
    var stackedValue = 0;
    
   for (var i =0; i < dataSeries.length; i++) {
      if (dataSeries[i].stack === stackNumber) {
        stackedValue = stackedValue + dataSeries[i].data[0][1];
      }
    }
    
    return stackedValue;
  }
  
  // display a marking value
  function displayMarkingValues(markings) { 
    $.each(markings, function(i, marking) {  
      var offset = plot.pointOffset({x: marking.xaxis.to, y: marking.yaxis.to });
    
      $('<div class="data-point-value">------ $' + marking.yaxis.to + '</div>').css( {
        left: offset.left,
        top: offset.top - 8,
      }).appendTo(plot.getPlaceholder());
    });
  }
  
  function displayBarLabels(plotData) {
    $.each(plotData, function(i, data) {
      if (data.bars.show) {
        var stackedValue = findStackedValue(plotData, data.stack);
       var offset = plot.pointOffset({x: data.data[0][0], y: stackedValue});
        
        $('<div class="data-point-label">' + data.label + '</div>').css({
          left: offset.left - 35,
          top: offset.top + 50,
        }).appendTo(plot.getPlaceholder());
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#graph {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 600px;
}

.data-point-value {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.data-point-label {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/emmerich/flot-orderBars/master/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/flot/flot/master/source/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the approach using flot!  Before your response, I resigned myself to using a straight CSS approach and lots of divs.  I fundamentally prefer your approach as I was having to do lots of server-side calculations for top/bottom placement relative to the pixel height of my containing div.  Your approach is so much cleaner -- thanks again for the inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/). Its pretty easy to customize and it works well in all browsers. Also have a look at [Chart JS](http://www.chartjs.org/). Its pretty cool and its open source

Answer (score 1):

I'v been using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) for a while. While it is sweet at first glance, and you really can do super awesome stuff with it out of the box, it can be really limiting later on when you come across the need to do some simple/custom details that are not in documentation. For example: label outside the chart; turning off background for bar chart, doughnut bar with 1 value (for example - i have doughnut chart, with value 20%, i want the difference to be colored - you cant do that).

Of course all these stuff can be addressed and made with customizing .js file, and extending it but **if you don't have time for that** and you want out of the box solution, you can be stuck on simple detail so i suggest reading [full docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started) to see if it is up to your expetations.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) with the caveat the the learning curve is steep; let me try to explain:

In something like chart.js, chartist,etc you provide the data, chart type and some configuration and you have your chart. In D3, it is a bit more complicated in the sense that D3 provides the framework for displaying and interacting with data via the Dom elements you design and specify.( Mostly svg's although you can also use divs,spans etc)

While it feels daunting at first and the documentation is basically an [API Reference](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md), there are [hundreds of examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock) you can use as base or inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

I'v been using ([ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/), [Morris](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/), [Inline Charts](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/)) for dashboard. It may help you much to customize the chart

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Chartist.js](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/). It is fully responsive with great flexibility and DPI dependent.

you're able to style your charts with CSS in @media queries and lot of animation options. they have given examples for line chart, bar chart, pie chart with code. So it will definitely help you.

Answer (score 0):

I like [amCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/).
Can do all kinds of stuff and is free to use.

Answer (score 0):

Google gives you an interesting charting library.

May want to try that but it requires you to be connected to Google for it to work (can't run it offline).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shot at it with [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo). I adapted the 'Stacked and grouped column' example at http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped. 
Obviously there's work to be done in getting the labels and axes right, but I think this is a good start.

jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/saevj2n4/1/

[image: HighCharts Chart]

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            width: 200,
            height: 1000
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Profit']
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of fruits'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                //groupPadding: .45,
                pointPadding: 0,
                //pointWidth: 40,
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Min',
            data: [59.28 - 21.58 ],
            stack: 'Last Year',
            color: "#919191"
        }, {
            name: 'Max',
            data: [21.58 ],
            stack: 'Last Year',
            color: "transparent"           
        }, {
            name: 'Min',
            data: [ 57.15 - 32.5 ],
            stack: 'Last Month',
            color: "#6095c9"         
        }, {
            name: 'Max',
            data: [32.50],
            stack: 'Last Month',
            color: "transparent"
        }, {
            name: 'Min',
            data: [54.81 - 47.14 ],
            stack: 'Last Week',
            color: "#745f8e"
        }, {
            name: 'Max',
            data: [47.14],
            stack: 'Last Week',
            color: "transparent"
        }]
    });
});
```